# Symfony2, delimiters for a form

Tags: forms, symfony

I noticed that when I generate a form with a builder like this:

```
$builder
        ->add('valide')
        ->add('adresse', new \Acme\CoreBundle\Form\AdresseType())
        ->add('prestations', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'AcmeAppartBundle:Prestation',
            'property' => 'nom',
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true)
        );
```

The 'presations' field (which is a complete form) can be rendered with twig like that :`{{ form(form.prestations) }}`

My question is : is there a way to do the same for the rest of the form? I mean the same that : `{{ form(form) }}`
But without the `{{ form(form.prestations) }}` part included in. (how to define 'sections' of a form in the formType)?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to change the render order so that `form.presentations` is rendered first and then the rest of the form, you can simply do this:

```
{{ form(form.prestations) }}
{{ form_rest(form) }}
```

When you do `form_rest(form)` it will render everything that hasn't been rendered before.

From the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-rest-view-variables):

> This renders all fields that have not yet been rendered for the given
>   form. It's a good idea to always have this somewhere inside your form
>   as it'll render hidden fields for you and make any fields you forgot
>   to render more obvious (since it'll render the field for you).

Comment: Yes i've seen it in the doc, it could be usefull unfortunatly I need to render `{{form(form.presations)}}` at the end of the form, I'll take a look on the link from dmnptr later. thanks for answering!

Comment: You should specify that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have parts of the form that you want to add/remove depending on certain conditions, you should use form events.

Take a look at the documentation here - http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html